# ERROR: Error from the Cuckoo Guest:

Tags: python

When trying to run executable files for malware anlysis in cuckoo i get the following error. i tried to search all over but i cant get a clear solution. Your help is highly appreciated

Error

```
[lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] ERROR: Error from the Cuckoo Guest: Analysis failed: The package "modules.packages.exe" start function raised an error: Unable to execute the initial process, analysis aborted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\fujkjd\analyzer.py", line 778, in <module>
    success = analyzer.run()
  File "C:\fujkjd\analyzer.py", line 626, in run
    (package_name, e)
CuckooError: The package "modules.packages.exe" start function raised an error: Unable to execute the initial process, analysis aborted.
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxERN.png)